# How to make an Observable synchronized collection C# .net 6

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-core, observablecollection

I use a
`SynchronizedCollection<SomeClass>` to synchronize a list between some threads. This works great, but now I would like to populate a text control always with the latest item added to the list.

It seems that this list is not observable so it does not have a `Changed` event. Any advice on how to accomplish this?